# Make 1:1 scaled image out of tall image without making it wide

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css

I was wondering if I could show width-matched part of an image within a div? I've tried using things like `width:100%;`, but that still shows the full tall image only way too wide. I'm using a 4-column Bootstrap template to try and print images. Here's my code (with another style code that didn't work out..):

```
echo "<div class='col-md-3 portfolio-item'>";
    echo "<a href='#'>";
        $url = $row['url'];
        echo "<img style='object-fit:contain;max-height:240px;' class='img-responsive' src='".$url."' alt=''>";
    echo "</a>";
echo "</div>";
```

Example of a tall image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SDZpp.jpg

How I want it to be displayed (top, bottom or middle doesn't matter): https://i.stack.imgur.com/XuEMb.jpg

How it is currently displayed (white square to the right of it): https://i.stack.imgur.com/9M8sK.png

If I set the `max-width` and `max-height` of the image anchor, can I display only part of it (top, bottom or middle doesn't matter) without having to crop a thumbnail myself?

Having a massively hard time explaining my problem, sorry about that. I'm not sure where to start, my Googling hasn't led me anywhere, probably not using the correct terms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your `.portfolio-item` is resized due to the image. You have to force a box of 1:1 ratio that will restrict the image (*with `overflow:hidden`*)

```css
.portfolio-item.square{position:relative}
.portfolio-item.square:before{
  content:'';
  display:block;
  padding-top:100%;
}
.portfolio-item.square > a{
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class='col-md-3 portfolio-item square'>
      <a href='#'>
        <img style='max-width:100%;' class='img-responsive' src='http://i.imgur.com/ux6PckG.jpg' alt=''>"
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class='col-md-3 portfolio-item square'>
      <a href='#'>
        <img style='max-width:100%;' class='img-responsive' src='http://i.imgur.com/ux6PckG.jpg' alt=''>"
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class='col-md-3 portfolio-item square'>
      <a href='#'>
        <img style='max-width:100%;' class='img-responsive' src='http://i.imgur.com/ux6PckG.jpg' alt=''>"
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class='col-md-3 portfolio-item square'>
      <a href='#'>
        <img style='max-width:100%;' class='img-responsive' src='http://i.imgur.com/ux6PckG.jpg' alt=''>"
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Even better would be to set the image as a background to the `a` tag, this way you will have control over how to align the image (*top/bottom/right...*) through `background-position:...`

Comment: Worked much better as a background. Thank you.